# Using normalized weights for least squares

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, least-squares

I have three arrays: x, y and signal strength. I would like to fit line to x and y using `signal_strength` array as weights. The idea is to give more weights to samples with higher `signal_strength`, which is in arbitrary units. I tried the following:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

noise = np.random.uniform(-20,20,10)
x = np.linspace(0,100,10) + noise
y = np.linspace(0,50,10) + noise

signal_strength = [52., 42., 29., 6., 25, 9, 78, 2, 19, 49]

x = x.reshape(-1,1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model_weights = linear_model.LinearRegression()

model.fit(x, y)
model_weights.fit(x, y, sample_weight=signal_strength)

line_X = np.arange(x.min(), x.max())[:, np.newaxis]
line_y = model.predict(line_X)
line_y_weights = model_weights.predict(line_X)
print("LR", model.coef_)
print("LR + weights", model_weights.coef_)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(line_X, line_y, color="red", label="LR")
plt.plot(line_X, line_y_weights, color="blue", label="LR + weights")

plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

My question is, do I need to normalize the signal strength by dividing all values by the maximum? and what is the maximum and minimum values I can use as weights?

I would like to understand how `sample_weight` works.

Comment: In your code, `len(sample_weight)` needs to be `X.shape[1]`.  You can normalize X with `model = LinearRegression(normalize=True)`, although `normalize` is deprecated.  There are other recommended scalers and normalizers.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Indeed. I just corrected my weights array. However, my question is more about understanding how 'sample_weights' work. For example: how does it treat the 'signal_strength' values in that case? And whether or not these values (weights) need to be normalized somehow.

Comment: It depends.  You can research how weights can be used with OLS regression.  Just as important, since this relates to some physical/confidence properties, you need to determine how your `signal_strength` measurements should affect the fit.  Is it really just signal power in some bandwidth?  ... SNR/SNIR measurement? ... Is it a linear or log measurement?   ...etc.